# How to create a custom range slider in wordpress form?

Tags: forms

I want to create a custome range slider in a form of  wordpress custom theme.since,i am a beginner,i dont know how to get values from range slider too.Any advice?

Comment: Since this is more of an HTML or PHP question, you might try asking on StackOverflow or looking up how to manipulate forms with PHP.

Comment: you might find this useful, since there are so many styling options: http://danielstern.ca/range.css/